# Are user names ever case sensitive?

Tags: security, user-interface

I'm looking at some code that converts user names to lower case, before storing them. I'm 90% sure this is ok, but are there systems out there that actually require case sensitivity on the user names (specifically in the health industry)?

**Note:** my particular code is not at the point of entry.  We are taking user names from other systems.  The worry I have is depending on those systems (which may or may not be under our control) to consistently pass us usernames in the same case as each other (when describing the same user).

Also of note - the code is:

```
userName.toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH)
```

Are all user names in english?  Is this just so it matches collation in the database? Note that (in java at least) `String.toLowerCase()` is defined as `String.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())`

Answer (score 24):

unix logins are case sensitive...

Are there any other systems that do this?

Comment: Is someone able to tell me why this is getting downvoted?  It's not a specific answer in my case, but I would have thought it useful for others.  What gives?

Comment: Well, this answers exactly what was asked. It points out a case where user names are case sensitive. I upvoted this.

Comment: _Are there any other systems that do this?_ Yes of course, e.g. [Wikipedia](http://www.wikipedia.org) user names are case-sensitive.

Comment: Not sure if it's changed since 2016 but when logged in Wikipedia shows my username as title cased, but I log in using an all lowercased username ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 7):

toLowerCase has only one reason for it to accept a locale:

since small letter i has a dot in every standard language, the letter I is transformed to a i with a dot.

but in turkish, there is also a capital letter İ with a dot above. this is transformed to a small letter i.

the "regular" turkish capital I is transformed to a small ı - without a dot.

so, unless your turkish usernames are all called IiI1I1iiII, i would hardly worry about this.

every other language than turkish has a identical toLowerCaseImplementation. so you could chose Locale.ENGLISH or Locale.GERMAN or whatever..just make sure you do not pick turkish.

see the [javadoc for more detailed information](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toLowerCase(java.util.Locale))

edit: thanks to utku karatas i could/copy paste the correct glyphs in ths post.

Comment: Have a problem with Turkish? Anyways no reason to be lazy, when using an invariant locale is all the work required to support a few million potential users.

Comment: No turkish keyboard Andreas? :) Let me illustrate the issue... lower("I") = "ı", lower("İ") -> "i".

Comment: And btw Jeff has a lengthy post about this issue.. http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001075.html

Comment: I'd like to point out that it's **not** only the Turkish language which has a different `toLocaleLowerCase` implementation. 
Currently there are 3 languages with different rules, namely Lithuanian, Turkish and Azeri.
[Source](http://www.unicode.org/Public/UCD/latest/ucd/SpecialCasing.txt)

Comment: "every other language than turkish has a identical toLowerCaseImplementation" - It's more complicated than that. For instance, in german SS -> ß. Greek has 2 ways to write lower case Σ depending on word position.

Answer (score 3):

Using case sensitive username/passwords is an easy way to increase security, so the question is, how much do you care about security vs usability.  Just keep in mind that the way you're looking at solving the case insensitivity may have some localization problems, but if you don't care then don't worry about it.

Answer (score 2):

Lowercasing the user name using the English locale is bound to cause you problems. I would suggest lowercasing using the invariant culture.

Comment: In Java, this would be Locale.ROOT

Comment: Invariant culture in .NET is english locale anyway.

Comment: @Joshua - this is an internal implementation detail you should not rely on.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on context, but in the Informix dialect of SQL, there are 'owners' (basically equivalent to a schema in standard SQL), and how you write the owner name matters.

```
SELECT *
    FROM someone.sometable, "someone".sometable,
         SOMEONE.sometable, "SOMEONE".sometable
```

The two quoted names are definitely different; the two unquote names are mapped to the same name, which (depending on database mode) could be either of the other two.  There is some code around which does case-conversion on the (unquoted) names.  Fortunately, most of the time you don't need to specify the name, and when you do you write the name without quotes and it all works; or you write the name with quotes and are consistent and it all works.  Occasionally, though, people like me have to really understand the details to get programs to work sanely despite all the hoops.

Also, (as Stephen noted) Unix logins are case-sensitive, and always have been.  I believe Windows logins are mostly case-insensitive - but I don't experiment with that (there are too many ways to get screwed up on Windows without adding that sort trickery to the game).

If you really want to confuse someone on Unix, give them a numeric user name (e.g. 123) but give them a different UID (e.g. 234).

Answer (score 1):

Kerberos, which can be used in Windows environments too, has case sensitivity problems. You can configure it in a certain way to ensure that case sensitivity issues will not arise, but it can go the other way too.

Answer (score 0):

If your only goal is differentiating one user from another, it seems logical that you would want more than case to be a factor.

Answer (score 0):

I have never encountered a system that enforced case-sensitivity on usernames (nor would I want to).

Most likely the code forces them lowercase at the point of entry as an attempt to prevent case-sensitivity problems later.

Comment: I have edited to note that our system is not the one providing access.

Comment: `Wikipedia usernames are case sensitive, but the first letter is always automatically capitalized` taken from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Username_policy

Comment: While Wikimedia / Wikipedia / MediaWiki usernames are case-sensitive, the software prevents two usernames that differ only by capitalisation.